# Iterating through a non-contiguous range in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Consider a Google Spreadsheet. Each row contains some measurement data from a given patient.

I wrote a Google Script function which iterates through the selected rows and exports each patient's data into a separate PDF file.

```
function Export() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("master-lab");
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var row0 = range.getRow();
  var row1 = row0 + range.getNumRows();
  for (i = row0; i < row1; ++i) {
    ExportRow(i);
  }
}
```

This code does not work if the user selects a non-contiguous array of rows, like in the following figure:

[image]

Is it there a way/workaround to iterate through non-contiguous ranges in Google Sheet?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is not with iterating through ranges (having an array of ranges and an additional `for` loop to go over them is not a problem). The issue is the script will not know what the ranges are.

Google Apps Script is unable to access multiple ranges selected by a user. Only the last selected range is visible to it. There is a feature request [Add support to allow use and manipulate disjoint Ranges](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761866) which was filed in 2014 and remains outstanding.

Answer (score 2):

[Since 2018](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761866), disjunct selected ranges can be accessed through the method [getActiveRangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactiverangelist):

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
```